# iphone: UIwebview curl effect

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I would like to make a standard view container which will give me the curl animation effect on multiple views.

Something like uiscrollview and paging, only with a different animation(curl).

I will be using UIwebviews as my separate pages.

The problem:
I do not know how to trap swipes in UIwebviews, But I see that UIscrollview implments this (swiping a uiwebview in a uiscrollview will bring me to the next view). I am therefore assuming that the implmentation of UIscrollview is trapping UIwebview swipes.

How can i achieve the same functionality? I also need the UIWebview to keep functioning (as when embedding it in a uiscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is a subclass of UIResponder and thus responds to touch events (I assume this is what you mean when you say 'trap swipes'). Take a look at the documentation of [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder) for more information on touch events.